# LIKE using Multiple AND in MySql

Tags: php, mysql

```
select * from 
  name WHERE name LIKE 'a%' 
  AND LOWER(main_cat)='girl' 
  AND LOWER(sub_cat_url)='indian-girl-names' LIMIT 0,50
```

I want to find record name starting with `A` and also `AND` query multiple time.
I have following data in database but no result with above query.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

The names all start with capital "a"s.  So, try this:

```
select *
from name 
where name LIKE 'A%' and
      LOWER(main_cat)='girl' and
      LOWER(sub_cat_url)='indian-girl-names'
limit 0,50;
```

Note:  Using `limit` without an `order by` is suspicious and will probably cause unexpected results.